# How to protect static folder in express with jwt

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, jwt

I have application which is build on nodejs and angularjs ,where i am using  jwt token based authentication to authenticate and the api calls that is working fine

Even when the user is not login now application is service all the static resources how to avoid loading the application if the user is not login and redirect the user to login page

Finally i was able to fiqure it out in the app.js floder add the code sinpet
     app.use('/app/view/*', function(req, res, next) {

```
    if (!req.headers['authorization'] ) {
      res.sendfile('app/views/Error.html');

    } else {
      next();
    }
  });
```

this mean for the request coming with /app/view/ check if the header of the request contains the token generated with jwt

Comment: in client side, check the user's authentication and then allow him to access the static files

Comment: please elaborate on the same point me to some article or a example

Answer (score 2):

If your JWT is stored in a cookie you can use a road like this one :

```
router.all('/*', function(req, res, next){
  if (!req.cookies.session) {
    return res.json("ERROR");
  }
  else {
    ValidateCookieFunction(req.cookies.session, function(auth_state) {
      if (!auth_state)
          return res.json("ERROR");
      else
          next();
    });
  }
});
```

else you can provide your JWT in an HTTP-Header

```
router.all('/*', function(req, res, next){
  if (!req.headers['x-access-token']) {
    return res.json("ERROR");
  }
  else {
    ValidateJWTFunction(req.headers['x-access-token'], function(auth_state) {
      if (!auth_state)
          return res.json("ERROR");
      else
          next();
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I am not using cookies are session to store the token i have place the token in  $window object and written a interceptor to attack the request header with token

Comment: @DhanaLakshmi then you provide your JWT in an HTTP header, see my edited post

Comment: can jwt tokens be used for serving the static content of express bcoz i have a interceptor on server side which checks for the request which is starting with /api check whether the token is present are not if not send has unauthorized how can i use the same thing to serve my static resources

Comment: In the example I showed you, the road is : `router.all('/*'` so it checks for POST/GET in all URL before going to the new road (`next()`). If you serve your static content in /public you can make the road be  `router.all('/public/*'`

Comment: I am using the example some thing like this app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    if (!req.headers['Bearer']) {
  
      return res.json("ERROR");
    }
    else {
      next();

    }
  }); how to avoid for the route like login page and sign up page

Comment: @DhanaLakshmi did you manage to implement this ?